# Supressing warnings in production for wxWidgets application

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm creating a proof of concept before adopting or not wxWidgets to develop a project.

In a tutorial program, I've noticed a few warnings being displayed while resizing the window. Examples are:

```
(my_program:12795): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 14:08:21.430: gtk_box_gadget_distribute: assertion 'size >= 0' failed in GtkScrollbar

(my_program:12795): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:08:37.179: Negative content height -6 (allocation 6, extents 6x6) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)
```

Fair enough, I get those may be things I can check and prevent in code, but nevertheless, it was pretty harmless for the test program I was testing. But it did make me think that I don't want or need my end-users to see this kind of message.

So how can I hide these warnings from an end-user?

If anyone wants to see the code:

main.hpp:

```
#include "wx/wx.h"


class FlexGridSizer : public wxFrame {
 public:
  FlexGridSizer(const wxString& title);
};

class MyApp : public wxApp{
  public:
   virtual bool OnInit();
};
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "main.hpp"

FlexGridSizer::FlexGridSizer(const wxString& title)
    : wxFrame(NULL, -1, title, wxPoint(-1, -1), wxSize(270, 220)) {
  wxPanel* panel = new wxPanel(this, -1);

  wxBoxSizer* hbox = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);

  wxFlexGridSizer *fgs = new wxFlexGridSizer(3, 2, 9, 25);

  wxStaticText* text1 = new wxStaticText(panel, -1, wxT("A"));
  wxStaticText* text2 = new wxStaticText(panel, -1, wxT("B"));
  wxStaticText* text3 = new wxStaticText(panel, -1, wxT("C"));

  wxTextCtrl* tc1 = new wxTextCtrl(panel, -1);
  wxTextCtrl* tc2 = new wxTextCtrl(panel, -1);
  wxTextCtrl* tc3 = new wxTextCtrl(panel, -1, wxT(""), wxPoint(-1, -1),
                                   wxSize(-1, -1), wxTE_MULTILINE);

  fgs->Add(text1);
  fgs->Add(tc1, 1, wxEXPAND);
  fgs->Add(text2);
  fgs->Add(tc2, 1, wxEXPAND);
  fgs->Add(text3, 1, wxEXPAND);
  fgs->Add(tc3, 1, wxEXPAND);

  fgs->AddGrowableRow(2, 1);
  fgs->AddGrowableRow(1, 1);

  hbox->Add(fgs, 1, wxALL | wxEXPAND, 15);

  panel->SetSizer(hbox);

  Centre();
}

IMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp)

bool MyApp::OnInit() {
  FlexGridSizer* fgs = new FlexGridSizer(wxT("FlexGridSizer"));
  fgs->Show(true);

  return true;
}
```

Compile and run in a console, then start resizing the window, so that is b=has 0 height or width, then expand again, the messages will appear in the console.

Comment: I never used wxWidgets. but did you try what is mentioned in [Logging Overview](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/overview_log.html), [static bool wxLog::EnableLogging(bool  enable = true)](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_log.html#a58bbfc0831eb47f0d88c9350d1f6e02d) and  [wxLogNull Class Reference](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_log_null.html)

Comment: @t.niese I'm checking these resources, but for instance, adding `wxLog::EnableLogging(false);` on either `OnInit` method of the `FlexGridSizer` constructor changed nothing.

Comment: GTK is well known for its buggy (but mostly harmless) messages. Very few times wxWidgets is the cause.

Comment: Worth checking if there is a Gtk bug open for the associated messages. At time errors like that will be caused by Gtk failing to initialize a value (which can be harmless in most instances). I'm afraid you are not going to be able to suppress the warnings. However, make sure you are using the current WxWidgets that is using the current Gtk. These type errors were more common in older versions of Gtk.See, e.g. [GLib-CRITICAL Source ID xxx was not found when attempting to remove it](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=779605)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I'll chek this, and for information I'm using wxWidgets 3.1.3, for info. But even then, do people release wxWidgets built software that gives warnings to end users?

Comment: Short answer -- yes. Just as WxWidgets can't test every combination of Gtk widgets it uses, there are some many that have been developed over such a long period of time that they may not have produced errors with compilers of 10 years ago, but do today. Bugs like these (unless they actually cause harm) are slow to be fixed -- but ultimately will and will be included in the next release of whatever Gtk+ package WxWidgets uses (even Gtk+2 will get an occasional fix still) Also if it is Gtk+3 -- that has gone though so many changes in the past 5 years - easy for things to slip though.

Comment: FWIW I can't reproduce the problem using latest wx 3.1. In any case, these GTK messages are overly catastrophic, there is nothing really critical about not having enough space for a window, even if it does happen. Also, end users will (a) never see these messages as they don't start programs from the console and (b) won't be surprised by them if they do see them as plenty of Gnome apps regularly trigger GTK warnings/errors too.

Comment: @VZ. Now that you mentioned it, I used to call Matlab from console when using linux, because I simply never could start it otherwise. And there would be a GTK message annoying me. But one thing is not worrying about such message in a mature software from a big company, the other is ignoring these messages on a small application by a small company.

Comment: @VZ.: Current Eclipse (2020-03) EMF creates a dialog and because of incorrect sizing, that dialog is useless (it hides most of the content and is not resizable). It drops a lot of "assertion 'size >= 0' failed in GtkScrollbar". I would consider that critical, as  I am unable to use that dialog.

Comment: @TFuto Sorry, I don't know what EMF is. Of course there is a bug if the dialog is too small, but my point was that you often have these GTK warnings even when the final size is fine because they can be given before the window is laid out and so there is a very high chance of them being false positives.